# Extract strings before a special character in PostgreSQL 11

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have following values in a postgresql table. How can I extract all the string before '(' wherever it is present

```
col1
BCR-ABL (translocation) | MLL-AF4 (translocation) | E2A-PBX1 (translocation) | TEL-AML1 (translocation) | c-MYC (rearrangement) | CRLF2 (rearrangement) | PAX5 (rearrangement) 
EVC1 | EVC2 
EBF3 
TMCO1
```

The desired output is:

```
col1
BCR-ABL | MLL-AF4 | E2A-PBX1 | TEL-AML1 | c-MYC | CRLF2 | PAX5  
EVC1 | EVC2 
EBF3 
TMCO1
```

I am using following regex to extract that, but it is only excluding the last (

```
^(.*) \(.*
```

Comment: Try `regexp_replace(col1, '\([^)]+\)', '', 'g')`

Comment: It worked, could you please explain it, if possible. Thanks

Comment: The `\(` is to find an opening paren.  The `[^)]+` looks for one or more characters that are not closing paren.  The `\)` looks for a closing paren.  (you might want to make that `\) ?` to deal with the extra space).  The replacement is an empty string.  The `'g'` flag is for "global".

Comment: Wait, is that one string, with all the values separated by `|`? And you want to get the part before the parenthesis for each value individually, not just the part before the first parenthesis in the entire string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '\s*\([^()]*\)', '', 'g') AS col2 FROM test
```

See an online [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f3d84/4/0) and a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nJCiEc/1).

---

- `\s*` - 0+ (Greedy) whitespace characters;
- `\([^()]*\)` - 0+ non-paranthesis between escaped literal opening- & closing paranthesis.

---

A possible "better" solution is to avoid potentially false positives if these paranthesis can also be in a value before the delimiters:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '\s*\([^()]*\)(\s*\||$)', '\1', 'g') AS col2 FROM test
```

Here we use a backreference to whichever option was captured in the alternation. See an online [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b753a/2/0) and an online regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2KSsUY/1)

---

- `\s*` - 0+ (Greedy) whitespace characters;
- `\([^()]*\)` - 0+ non-paranthesis between escaped literal opening- & closing paranthesis;
- `(\s*\||$)` - A 1st capture group to match 0+ whitespace characters (to avoid having to trim a potential trailing space later) and a literal pipe-symbol *or* the end-line anchor.